# Vector as parameter in #()

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to pass a parameter as `#(.name(value))`, but it's a vector.
I tried `.name[2:0]({0,1})` and QuartusII returns the error:

> ...near text [ ; expeting {

There is a way to solve this problem without dividing vector or use `parameter name= {value1, value2, ...};` ?

Comment: Could you show some more code?

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't have part selects in the module instantiation. Try something like this instead:

```
some_module
 #( .name({1'b0,2'b01}) )
U0
  ( /*ports*/ );
```

Comment: I replaced ".name[2:0]({0,1})"  with  ".name({1b'0,1b'1})" and it worked.
Thanks